# Where to go from here when manipulating files

Tags: c, arrays, string, file, structure

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct student
{
    int stdntnum[8];
    float homework;
    float lab;
    float midterm;
    float finalgrade;
    float overall;
};

int main()
{
    FILE *filePtr, *file2Ptr;
    char headers[30];
    int string[100];

    filePtr = fopen("lab5_inputFile.txt", "r");
    file2Ptr = fopen("Lab5_outputFile.txt", "w");
    fgets(headers, 30, filePtr);
    printf("%s", headers);
    fprintf(file2Ptr, "%s\toverall grade\n", headers);
    fclose(filePtr);
    fclose(file2Ptr);
}
```

Hey guys,my assignment is to manipulate the example of file shown here:

```
ID          homework    lab     midterm  final

1016807     89.0        93.0    78.0     50.0

1211272     84.0        78.0    23.0     59.0
```

I've gotten the headings to read and write on the new file, however I'm unsure how to approach the second part. I need to change the first few numbers of the **ID** column to x `[e.g: xxx6807]`, as well as use the following grades to calculate an **overall grade** and have that column print to the new text as well. any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks! (I've also gotten the **overall** column to print, let me know if there's a more effective way.)

```
ID      homework    lab     midterm  final  overall

1016807 89.0        93.0    78.0     50.0   70.9

1211272 84.0        78.0    23.0     59.0   59.26
```

Just an example of what the output file should produce, any assistance on what my next approach should be and why (in as layman's terms as possible) would greatly help!! [the grade weights are 10%, 20%, 30%, and 40% respectively]

Comment: You still need to go back and add some error handling to the code, you did none.

Comment: Just to get a better overview over what you are doing, could you paste the current printing output of your program?

Comment: Of course there are many ways to achieve the same thing. One way would be to use a loop to read each line using fscanf. That would allow you to get each column of each line in a seperate variable. Then you can manipulate each variable as you like and write the result back out to file.

Comment: after reading the headers line, remove the trailing newline, then strcat a tab and "overall\n"

Comment: to change the first 3 characters of the ID to 'xxx', read the ID field into a string, then string[0] = 'x'; string[1] = 'x'; string[2] = 'x';  then use printf to output the modified string

Comment: it looks like the overall field is the sum of the homework, lab, midterm, final fields (all converted to int via atoi()) then shift right 2 (or divide by 4) to obtain the overall value.

Comment: My pointer keeps resetting its position, i'm trying to send the headers then continue from that point altering the variables, yet i can't get to the second line.